# Android Php Mysql insertion repetition

Tags: php, android, mysql, httpclient

Well at the moment my Android app simply takes user's Name and Country and on submit inserts that data into mysql connected with httpclient in php and in the next activity (Android) it reads all the data fro my db and displays it. The problem is that each insertion store 2 same values in the database whereas there is only one query in my php script. I completely dont understand the science behind it.Looking forward for support. Android Insertion COde:

```
httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
httppost= new HttpPost("http://......./wp-mail.php"); 
//add your data
nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
// Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",et.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim())); 
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

php insertion code:

```
<?php  
    //echo 'this';
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $database = "...";
    $username = "...";
    $password = "xyz";

    $cn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($database);

    $name=$_POST['username'];
    $country=$_POST['password'];

    $insert="INSERT INTO `downloader_details`(id,name,country) VALUES (NULL,'$name','$country')";

    $result1 = mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Done Loading";
    mysql_close($cn);
    exit();
 ?>
```

php Display code:

```
<?php  
    //echo 'this';
$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "...........";
$username = "..........";
$password = ".........";

$cn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database);

$query="SELECT * FROM `downloader_details` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 8";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

echo "Following people around the world downloaded this application";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

{
   echo $row['name']. " From ". $row['country']."\n\n";
}


mysql_close($cn);
exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code looks ok. Should be done only once. The `httpclient` may be requesting two times i guess.. 
1. check for this in android.
2. The other idea is make both columns unique if that's not a problem so insertion will not happen.

Comment: Working on the HttpClient's request part. Is there anything to do with the GET and POST methods? Im using Post on the either sides but i think establish the conenction again in 2nd activity is causing the problem mainly

Comment: show where all you call the httpclient to send req. Problem might lie there.. try debugging

Comment: sorted out.. I was resending the httppost request somehow in the response section. Works like a charm now. Thank you for the help. I think I should accept your answer as it showed the possible area of trouble if not the exact answer.Seems justified.